# How can I give to Gaussian processes a tensor (length, n_step, nb_features) as input?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gaussian-process

Does anyone know how we can can give to gaussian processes of sklearn a tensor as input ?
I did it with neural networks but I would try it for a gaussian process.

Comment: "I would try it for a gaussian process" - so, _have_ you actually tried this? What happens when you try it?

Comment: Dimension is the problem tensors have 3 dimensions and Gaussian processes accept only 2D arrays.